# p tag to dynamic text width

Tags: css

How can I make a `<p>` tag expand so that it is the right size for the content that will fill it. Just giving it padding does not seem to do that. And when I omit the `width` property, it expands to fill the entire width of its parent `<td>`. It has to be all inlined styles since it's email.

```
<p style="font-family:'helvetica', 'arial', 'sans-serif'; font-size:11pt; padding:7px 5px 5px 7px; background-color:#dddddd;">
    Purchase order {$sector_value['sector_info']['purchase_order']}
</p>
```

Comment: Can you show a sample fiddle?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just add `display:inline-block` to the paragraph! :)

http://jsfiddle.net/SZSFE

Comment: @1252748 You should accept this as the correct answer.